# Grep between two patterns in file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Example

```
Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00
abc
abc
abc
Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00
abc
abc
abc
abc
Date & Time : 2016-01-25 05:00:00
```

I want to calculate the total number of abc between two patterns (say 2016-01-23 and 01-24) and then (say 2016-01-24 to 2016-01-26) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ grep -zo 'Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00.*Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00' infile |
> grep -zo 'abc' | wc -l
3
$ grep -zo 'Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00.*Date & Time : 2016-01-25 05:00:00' infile |
> grep -zo 'abc' | wc -l
4
```

Treat the file as binary to ignore newlines (`-z`) and only retain what matches (`-o`), then match all occurrences of `abc` and count them (`wc -l`).

In a slightly better scriptable format:

```
$ pattern1='Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00'
$ pattern2='Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00'
$ grep -zo "$pattern1"'.*'"$pattern2" infile | grep -zo 'abc' | wc -l
3
```

A solution using sed (same pattern variables used as above):

```
$ sed -n "/$pattern1/,/$pattern2/{/abc/p}" infile | wc -l
3
```

This assumes that there is never more than one `abc` per line. If there is:

```
sed -n "/$pattern1/,/$pattern2/p" infile | grep -o 'abc' | wc -l
```

Comment: I wanted to wc -l between 'Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00' and 'Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00' ie) I need to put the exact case in the place of grep -oz'my exact pattern'. I tried but not working

Comment: @Sukan Well, yes, because you changed the question now.

Comment: @Benjawin  could you please tweak your answer then Thanks

Comment: @Sukan I'll do that. And it would have been super awesome if the question had reflected what you *actually* want the first time around.

Comment: Thanks for the udpated answer, but its not working I'm getting 0 as a o/p

I tried this, grep -zo 'Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00.*Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00' infile | grep -zo 'abc' | wc -l

Comment: @Sukan What grep version are you using? And your input file is called `infile`, yes?

Comment: Yes, infile is my file name. GNU grep 2.6.3 is the version I'm using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101495/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-sukan).

Answer (score 5):

A little state machine:

```
awk '/Date & Time/ {if (n) print n; n=0; next} {n++}' file
```

---

Between 2 specific dates

```
awk -v d1="2016-01-24" -v d2="2016-01-26" '
    /Date & Time/ {if ($5 >= d1) counting = 1; else if ($5 >= d2) exit; next}
    counting {count++}
    END {print count}
' file
```

Comment: Just edited my question, could you tweat the answer to satisfy that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Here is an awk example using a simple state indicating when the matching condition is found (state = 1)

```
BEGIN { state = 0; count = 0; }
/^Date \& Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00$/ { state = 1; next; }
/^Date \& Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00$/ {state = 2; next; }
/^abc$/ { if (state == 1) count++; }
END { print "Found abc " count " times."
```

Hope this helps.I have assumed that your abc is alone on a line, customize as appropriate.

Comment: please explain the logic

Comment: State = 0 means the first event (Date & Time line) hasn't been hit yet. State = 1  is set when that line is hit, and is the only state when matching abc lines are counted. When the second Date & Time event happens, the state is set to 2 and abc lines are no longer counted. The end clause prints out results.  The single line sed solution is my favorite, provided your input stays simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Perl can do it.

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt" 
Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00
abc
abc
abc
Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00
abc
abc
abc
abc
Date & Time : 2016-01-25 05:00:00
```

In Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -0777 -lne 'while(/(^Date & Time :[\d\-: ]+)\s+(\S.*?)(?=^Date & Time :[\d\-: ]+)/gsm){$x=$2=~tr/\n//; print "$1 $x lines\n"}'
Date & Time : 2016-01-23 02:00:00 3 lines
Date & Time : 2016-01-24 03:00:00 4 lines
```